# Oracle data compression pushing data upwards

Tags: sql, compression

I am in need of query such that there are 5 columns in a table

```
select pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4,pos5 from ci_pos ;
```

in the above fields any two can be null

example

```
pos1='hyd'
pos2='blr'
pos3=null
pos4=null
pos5='Chn'
```

or another example

```
pos1='hyd'
pos2=null
pos3='blr'
pos4=null
pos5='chn'
```

or

```
pos1=null
pos2='hyd'
pos3='blr'
pos4=null
pos5='chn'
```

etc like all the above cases.

I need to write a select query which will return output as follows

example:

```
pos1='hyd'
pos2='blr'
pos3=null
pos4=null
pos5='chn'
```

o/p should be:

```
pos1='hyd'
pos2='blr'
pos3='Hyd'
pos4=null
pos5=null
```

example 2:

```
pos1='hyd'
pos2=null
pos3='blr'
pos4=null
pos5='chn'
```

output

```
pos1='hyd'
pos2='blr'
pos3='chn'
pos4=null
pos5=null'
```

etc.

Basically I need to make the last two columns to null and push the data to above columns.

Comment: What are you asking?  What have you tried?  It sounds like you just want to write the query you started with:  a basic `SELECT` statement that selects the five columns from your table.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with *COALESCE*, Oracle function which returns the first of its arguments that is not a *NULL*. If you are sure that exactly 2 columns out of 5 are *NULL*, then the following code will give you the desired output:

```
with
  test_data as (
    select 'hyd' as pos1,
           'blr' as pos2,
            null as pos3,
            null as pos4,
            'chn' as pos5
      from dual
    union
    select null as pos1,
           null as pos2,
           'hyd' as pos3,
           'blr' as pos4,
           'chn' as pos5
      from dual
    union
    select 'hyd' as pos1,
           null as pos2,
           'blr' as pos3,
           null as pos4,
           'chn' as pos5
      from dual)
select
    coalesce(pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5) as pos1,
    case
      when pos1 is not null then coalesce(pos2, pos3, pos4)
      when pos1 is null and pos2 is not null then nvl(pos3, pos4)
      else pos4
    end as pos2,
    coalesce(pos5, pos4, pos3, pos2, pos1) as pos3,
    null as pos4,
    null as pos5
  from test_data
;
```

Explanation: we know that the last two columns will be *NULL*, so we just return *NULLs*. The first and the second columns are easy - just take the first non-*NULL* value for the first column (pos1). Same for the third column, but in reversed order of checking the columns.

Only with the second column you need to do some checking - if the first column is not *NULL*, then the last value will be in either pos2, pos3, or pos4. If pos1 *is* *NULL*, and the second column isn't, then the middle value will be either pos3 or pos4. Otherwise, the pos2 value is in the pos4 column.

Output:

```
POS1 POS2 POS3 POS4 POS5
---- ---- ---- ---- ----
hyd  blr  chn           
hyd  blr  chn           
hyd  blr  chn
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/4603)